# How to compare two or more conditions using decision tables(.xls) in drools?

Tags: java, drools

Code:

```
rule "rule1"
    when 
        testObject: Test(0 <= income && income <= 1000)

    then 
        System.out.println("rule 1 worked");
    end
```

I want to test two conditions in the decision table, If they are true. I will print out a Syslog in Java. but I could not do it. The above rule I wrote in ***.drl*** file. I want to apply the same condition in **.xls** decision table file. please give me your good suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The first step would be to read [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/drools-docs/html_single/#_rule_tables).

There you will find the following phrase: "If the cell is merged with one or more neighbours, a single pattern with multiple constraints is formed"

So, you basically need to merge the cells bellow the `CONDITION` cells into one and put each of your individual conditions as an individual column:

```
| CONDITION       | CONDITION          |
| Test                                 |   <--- These 2 cells are merged
| income => $1    | income <= $2       |
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: I merged the cell but it is not working. can you please elaborate me?

Comment: Please share your dtable and also add the DRL that is being generated.

Comment: For me this works as "and". Is there a way to put an "or" in the condition? Like (0 > value || value < 1000)

Comment: Yes, I also need to learn how to do OR logic in decision table,